# Как добавить символ \ (C#)

Tags: c#

Моя задача добавить символ \ в код

```
Console.WriteLine("Укажите путь к корневой папке GTA V. \n Пример ниже: D:\GTAV");
```

Но студио ругается на символ.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [@ (справочник по C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для путей к физическим данным используется символ `@` (verbatim string literal - буквальный строковый литерал), что позволяет использовать `\` в строках. Например:

```
string path = @"C:\users\...";
```

Или в обычном строковом литерале символ `\` можно получить так:

```
string path = "C:\\users\\...";
```

Comment: @aepot, не хорошо перекраивать ответы, либо напишите свой ответ, либо напишите автору комментарий и он дополнит сам, если захочет

Comment: По факту @aepot добавил только что можно в обычной строке получить знак \ с помощью \\, я хотел добавить это, но не стал так как такая практика не используется при написании пути, и тот вариант что он дополнил с путём:
string path = "C:\\users\\..." и выглядит не очень, и читается тяжело. Так что тут спорный момент.

Comment: Я видел изменения, даже если вы не против такой правки, в общем случае так делать нельзя

Comment: @АндрейNOP а я и не практикую подобные правки, но здесь материал уж больно примитивный. В любом случае, если автор против, он может либо подредактировать еще, либо откатить правку через историю изменений. Дополнение я дал скорее не для автора вопроса, а для будущих посетителей, которые нагуглят данное решение здесь.

Comment: В вопросе имеется символ `\n`. Считаю обязательным рассмотреть его при написании обоими способами.